# how to add a custom NPM postinstall script?

Tags: node.js, npm

whenever I run npm install it runs npm run postinstall. how can I add a custom post install script? so that after running npm install it runs npm run postinstall2?

Answer (score 1):

You call multiple scripts from `postinstall` by chaining them with `&&`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "script1": "",
    "script2": "",
    "postinstall": "script1 && script2"
  }
}
```

This should work on both Windows and Unix (Linux, macOS) terminals.

Comment: no i mean how do we have npm install call a script other than postinstall when its done.

Comment: @Jasmine what's the point? Just put anything from the other script into `"postinstall"`... or if you really _really_ cared, then `"postinstall": "npm run postinstall2"` but again, there's no point.